# CSS and HTML - How To Create Button Without Horizontal Line

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have a CSS/HTML question and I'm pretty new to it. For my Log In button, in html I have it listed as an a class. When I click it, it correctly goes to that url to the login page. But with the a class it creates that horizontal line below the font inside the button. I don't want that line.
But if I change it to a button class or p class, like the other buttons, the horizontal line disappears but then it doesn't actually go to the linked page. The link fails to work.

How can I make that horizontal line disappear below the font, and also have the link work? I know it has to do with html/css and not the actual link or url.

[image]

html:

```
<nav class="navbar">

        <div class="container">
       
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
      
      <p class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register for an 
 account</p><br>

      <p class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'five_day' %}">See Five Day 
Forecast</p><br>
    
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      
      <p class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</p><br>
      <hr>
      {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <p class="welcome">
                    <strong>Welcome {{ user.username }} !</strong></p>
                </p>
                {% endif %}
              </div>
```

css for the buttons:

```
.btn {

 position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;

}
```

Comment: See [text-decoration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply add a `text-decoration: none` to your a tag
Example :

```
 a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Using `<p>` tag won't help because it's used for normal text and not for a link .

Answer (score 4):

Just a few things about the default styles of Anchor Tags ( `<a></a>` )

- Links are underlined.
- Unvisited links are blue
- Visited links are purple.
- Hovering a link makes the mouse pointer change to a little hand icon.

Your problem is the first one i mentioned. you can remove the default styles with css. in you case you can do this with `text-decoration:none` property

```css
a {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:14px;
  color:black;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:10px 15px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">login</a>
<a href="#">logout</a>
<a href="#">register</a>
<a href="#">some button</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

> You should not link `<p>`, this is not true, if you need `<p>` it is better to put `<a></a>` inside `<p>` and link the `<a></a>`  .

And for remove horizontal line use:

```css
a{
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a `text-decoration: none;` to your anchor tag styling

```
.navbar a{
     text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: For links you have to use the <a> </a> tags.Paragraph tags won't work

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the text decoration (the underline) by using :

```css
a{
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.btn {

 position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">

        <div class="container">
       
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
      
      <p class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register for an 
 account</p><br>

      <p class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'five_day' %}">See Five Day 
Forecast</p><br>
    
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      
      <p class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</p><br>
      <hr>
      {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <p class="welcome">
                    <strong>Welcome {{ user.username }} !</strong></p>
                {% endif %}
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `text-decoration: none;` to your link

```
a {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

and don't put a button inside tag p directly,
if you'd like to have a button inside tag p,
this is the correct form:

```
<p>
   <a class="btn">
      Login
   </a>
</p>
```

or

```
<p>
   <button type="button" class="btn">
      Login
   </button>
</p>
```